# Loop inside a loop in R

Tags: r, iteration, nested-loops

I am trying to create an R code that puts another loop inside of the one I've already created.  Here is my code:

```
t <- rep(1,1000) 
omega <- seq(from=1,to=12,by=1)
for(i in 1:1000){
    omega <- setdiff(omega,sample(1:12,1))
    t[i] <- length(omega)
    remove <- 0
    f <- length(t [! t %in% remove]) + 1
 }
```

When I run this code, I get a number a trials it takes f to reach the zero vector, but I want to do 10000 iterations of this experiment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`replicate` is probably how you want to run the outer loop. There's also no need for the `f` assignment to be inside the loop. Here I've moved it outside and converted it to simply count of the elements of `t` that are greater than 0, plus 1.

```
result <- replicate(10000, {
  t <- rep(1, 1000) 
  omega <- 1:12
  for(i in seq_along(t)) {
    omega <- setdiff(omega,sample(1:12,1))
    t[i] <- length(omega)
  }
  sum(t > 0) + 1
})
```

I suspect your code could be simplified in other ways as well, and also that you could just write down the distribution that you're looking for without simulation. I believe your variable of interest is just how long until you get at least one of each of the numbers 1:12, yes?

Comment: this is exactly what I was looking for thank you!  I am basically trying to figure out how many trials it takes my omega sequence to be reduced to a numeric(0) (variable f) and then repeat the procedure multiple times to get an idea of the distribution of f.

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking to run your existing loop 10,000 times, like below?

```
t <- rep(1,1000) 
omega <- seq(from=1,to=12,by=1)
f <- rep(NA, 10000)
for(j in 1:10000) {
    for(i in 1:1000){
        omega <- setdiff(omega,sample(1:12,1))
        t[i] <- length(omega)
        remove <- 0
        f[j] <- length(t [! t %in% remove]) + 1
     }
}
```